# Solution for finding intersection of two lines described by parametric equation

Tags: proof-verification, parametric

Have two lines given by $p(t) = (-2, -1) + t(1,1)$ and $q(t) = (5,3) +s(4,1)$, and need find their intersection point.

My approach is :

Equating $x$ and $y$ coordinates for each line gives $-2 +t = 5 +4s$ and $-1 +t = 3 +s$, giving rise to the system:

$$
\begin{align}
t-4s =& \ 7 \\
t -s =& \ 4 \\
\end{align}
$$

Solving the system gives $t= 3, s=-1$, so the solution is (3,1).

Comment: Your approach is quite right.except that you need to put the values of $t$ and $s$ in the parametric equations, to get the intersection point. So your intersection point is $(-2,-1)+3(1,1)=(1,2)=(5,3)+(-1)(4,1)$

Comment: Thanks, but being parametric I suspected error; even though it is about intersection point of  two lines only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculation is ok but the solution should be (1,2).

$$p(3) = (-2, -1) + 3(1,1)=q(-1) = (5,3) -(4,1)=(1,2)$$

Comment: Thanks for that.